# What is the Polish version and meaning of ''Don't make a village?''

Tags: meaning, translation

Someone at my work had this on his t-shirt and said it's a real typical Polish saying and found it hard to explain the meaning in English.

Comment: You may have to include the exact Polish words and hope someone here knows Polish. I'm not sure if this sort of thing is within the scope of what we do here.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Not as rare as you may think to find Polish speakers here...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about Polish, not English. (See the Help on this point).

Answer (score 3):

If the words were *Nie rób wioski*, that literally means "Don't make a village" but idiomatically means "Don't be embarrassing/crude/thoughtless" or "Don't act like a peasant".

[Reference](https://www.academia.edu/14330274/_Thanks_from_the_Mountain_Humorous_Calques_in_Ponglish_as_an_Output_of_Language_Contact_and_Language_Creativity):

> Don’t make a village!
>    Polish original:
>    Nie rób wioski!
>   Meaning: ‘Don’t behave so embarrassingly.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this website](https://www.e-angielski.com/don%E2%80%99t-make-village-czyli-nie-rob-wiochy) it means

> don’t make a scene, don’t act like a country bumpkin

I imagine that the nearest English equivalents are **don't make a fuss** or **Chill!** but with the implication that urbane sophisticates never lose their tempers and make an unseemly row. There's obviously a cultural difference in the last part!